# java- Big O Notation- difference between MlogN and MlogM?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

If I wanted to find the dominant term of `M log (N) + M log (M )`, what should I do? What is the difference between MlogN and MlogM???

Answer (score 2):

Which one is dominant will depend on whether `M > N` or `M < N`. If `M > N`, `Mlog(N) < M log(M)`. If `M < N`, then `M log(N) > M log(M)`. A full analysis:

- Holding M constant and allowing N to vary, this is `O(log(N))`
- Holding N constant and allowing M to vary, this is `O(M log(M))`
- Allowing both N and M to vary, this is `O(M log(N) + M log(M)) = O(M(log(N) + log(M)) = O(M log(MN))`.

Ask yourself whether you are looking at a particular case or class of inputs where there is a definite relationship between `M` and `N` and, if so, use that relationship to derive your answer. Otherwise, in general, there is no single "dominant" term since what dominates will depend upon the relationship between `N` and `M`.

That said - increasing `M` alone increases the value of the expression faster than increasing `N` alone, if you're comparing like increases.